# Flask,wtforms post empty form back

Tags: python, post, flask, wtforms

I am a new learner. What I want is showing the values and when I clicked the submit button, the value could be posted back. However, the first step is done, but it posted nothing back. I have checked the `request.form` have datas. The following is my code:

```
from flask_wtf import Form
from wtforms import TextField,SelectField,FieldList,SubmitField,FormField  #   不能引入* 否则会顶掉前面的Form，导致validate方法不能用
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired
from flask import Flask,render_template,request,redirect,url_for,flash
import pandas as pd  
import wtforms_json
import json
wtforms_json.init()

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'you-will-never-guess'

dat = pd.read_csv('trading_config.csv',dtype={'code': str},encoding='gbk')
js = dat.to_dict(orient = 'records')
#js = wtforms_json.flatten_json(json.loads(js))

class TradingForm(Form):
    code = TextField('code')
    trading_stage = SelectField('trading_stage', 
                      choices=[('wait','wait'),('signal','signal'),
                               ('exit','exit'),    ('exclude','exclude')],default = '' )
    trading_mode  = SelectField('trading_mode', 
                      choices=[('-1','-1'),('1','1'),('2','2')],default = '')
    trading_account = TextField('trading_account')
    submit = SubmitField("Send")

class ListForm(Form):
    trading = FieldList(FormField(TradingForm), min_entries = 5)    

@app.route('/success', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def success():
    return render_template('success.html')

@app.route('/', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def submit():
    form = ListForm()

    trading_form = TradingForm()
    if 'update' in request.form and request.method =='POST':
        if form.validate == True:
             flash(form.errors)
        if form.validate_on_submit() == False:

             flash(form.data)
             flash(request.form)
             flash(form.errors)
        else:
            print form
            return redirect (url_for('success'))
            #return  render_template('hello.html', form=form,trading_form =   TradingForm())

    for item in js:
            trading_form = TradingForm(**item)              
            form.trading.append_entry(trading_form)     
    return render_template('hello.html', form=form)     


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug = True)
```

And the `html` is:

```
    {% for message in get_flashed_messages() %}
        <div class="flash">{{ message }}</div>
    {% endfor %}
<form method="POST"  action="http://localhost:5000/">
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    {{ form.csrf_token }}
    {{ form.trading.csrf_token }}
<fieldset>
    <table>
    <tr>
             <th> 股码            </th>  <th>交易状态    </th>
             <th> 策略模式        </th>  <th>交易账户   </th>
        </tr>
      {% for l in form.trading %}    
        <tr>
            <td>{{ l.code.data}}        </td>  <td>{{ l.trading_stage.data}}       </td>
            <td>{{ l.trading_mode.data}}</td>  <td>{{ l.trading_account.data}}  </td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}  
    </table>
    <input type="submit" name="update" value="update">

</fieldset>
 </form>
```

The `Get` is, it works well:

[image: Screenshot of the form]

When I clicked the button the forms data turns into empty data set:

```
{'trading': [{'trading_account': u'', 'code': u'', 'trading_stage': u'',     'submit': False, 'trading_mode': u''}, {'trading_account': u'', 'code': u'',
```

But, the `request.form` has all the data, what's wrong with the process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe the problem is that the `request.form` is ImmutableMultiDict like ('code', u'600844'), ('code', u'600848'), ('code', u'601888'),does not be constructed by form(request.form)